# SQL - ORDER BY Timestamp Array Data does not work

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, sql-order-by, sql-timestamp

I have a table with schema as below

```
fields. TIME_256Hz  TIMESTAMP   REPEATED    
fields. SAC_ACCELX  FLOAT   REPEATED    
fields. SAC_ACCELY  FLOAT   REPEATED    
fields. SAC_ACCELZ  FLOAT   REPEATED    
fields. SAC_GYROX   FLOAT   REPEATED    
fields. SAC_GYROY   FLOAT   REPEATED    
fields. SAC_GYROZ   FLOAT   REPEATED    
fields. SAC_PRESSURE    FLOAT   REPEATED    
fields. TARGET  STRING  REPEATED
```

The table looks like

[image]

I try to sort the data with timestamp using this command

```
select * from liftpdm.liftpdm_2.acc8 
order by fields.TIME_256Hz desc
```

BUT

I keep getting the following error:

```
ORDER BY does not support expressions of type ARRAY<TIMESTAMP> at [2:10]
```

I tried to change the Datatype to Datetime, string but same error.

Please suggest how to sort out this data

Thanks

Comment: Do you actually *need* to have the fields `REPEATED`?

Comment: It is the mode. I tried Nullable but that is wrong

Comment: I get following error when I change to Nullable                                                                              {
  "errors" : [ {
    "debugInfo" : "",
    "location" : "fields.time_256hz",
    "message" : "Array specified for non-repeated field.",
    "reason" : "invalid"
  } ],
  "index" : 0
}

Answer (score 2):

Reproducible error:

```sql
WITH data AS (
  SELECT [1,2] arr UNION ALL
  SELECT [2,1] UNION ALL
  SELECT [4,5,6]
)

SELECT * FROM data
ORDER BY arr

# ORDER BY does not support expressions of type ARRAY<INT64> at [8:10]
```

First you need to decide what do you really want to `ORDER BY`, as ordering by an array doesn't make much sense.

Some alternatives:

```sql
SELECT * FROM data
ORDER BY arr[SAFE_OFFSET(0)]
```

[image]

```sql
SELECT * FROM data
ORDER BY arr[SAFE_OFFSET(1)]
```

[image]

```sql
SELECT * FROM data
ORDER BY ARRAY_LENGTH(arr) DESC
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, a very important pointer. You are right, why would I need to order by arrays. Actually I need to order the entire column but the column has arrays of 256 records per row. So I need to somehow have the table like this from your example                       Rows =[1,2,3,4,5,6,7] and arr=[1,2,2,1,4,5,6] then I need to do order by on it. Can you suggest a way of doing it? thanks

Comment: Post a new question please!